# Convert CSV with dynamic columns to parquet

Tags: csv, apache-spark, parquet

I have csv files for a table that have dynamic columns with uncertain order:

csv file 1:

```
name, id, age, job
Amy, 001, 30, SDE
```

csv file 2:

```
id, job, name
002, PM, Brandon
```

I converted the csv files to parquet files in pyspark,

```
spark.read.csv(input_path, header = True).write.parquet(output_path)
```

and when I read the parquet using sparksql, the data has been shifted.

```
name, id, age, job
Amy, 001, 30, SDE
002, PM, Brandon
```

What I want is:

```
name, id, age, job
Amy, 001, 30, SDE
Brandon, 002, null, PM
```

I know parquet is a columnar format. When it comes to reordering, it should be able to write to parquet by column names, so the data won't get shifted. Or, the problem could be the read.csv because its formats depend on ordering, so it won't work in dynamic order.

Is there any config I can add to the code to make it work? or any other ways?

Comment: How are you reading data? using spark or hive?

Comment: @Piyush Patel I'm using spark.

Comment: I replied below if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `mergeSchema=true` option as below.

```scala
scala> spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/csv_test/")

scala> res16.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- job: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)


scala> res16.show
+---+---+-------+----+                                                          
| id|job|   name| age|
+---+---+-------+----+
|001|SDE|    Amy|  30|
|002| PM|Brandon|null|
+---+---+-------+----+
```

Please, beware schema merging is expensive operation.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried. The columns are still shifted. I found out the issue is in the read.csv(). The read.csv() makes the columns mismatched. So the parquet files already have shifted schema. The merge schema doesn't help. :(

Comment: Did you use `header=True` while reading? I used header=true and it did cause problems while reading without mergeSchema

Comment: Can you try first reading file using `spark.read.csv` if it actually reads with correct column names? Reading must be correct with `header=True` option. I don't have much exposure to Pyspark but with Scala Spark, it was fine for me.

Comment: yeah, I used ```spark.read.csv``` with ```header=True``` option. The columns are already shifted.